# How to display live video stream from ffmpeg in C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, udp

I am trying to get an output from FFmpeg.exe to display live on my wpf media player. The inputs to FFmpeg are an IP camera and a video file (mp4).

The WPF media player needs a URI as the input. So, I have tried hosting a Udp server for FFmpeg to post to (which I can log the data coming in on the console). Then I try to get the stream using the media player, but no success.

My Udp listener:

```
UdpClient _udpServer = new UdpClient(5000);
UdpClient _udpClient = new UdpClient(5001);
private void UdpListen() {
   while (true)
   {
      IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
      Byte[] receiveBytes = _udpServer.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
      if (RemoteIpEndPoint.ToString() != "192.168.1.110:5001")
      {
         IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.110"), 5001);
         _udpClient.Send(receiveBytes, receiveBytes.Length, ep);
      }
      Console.WriteLine("receive data from " + RemoteIpEndPoint.ToString() + ": " + receiveBytes.Length);
   }
}
```

The ffmpeg output: ... -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.110:5000

I pass this into the media player: udp://192.168.1.110:5001

I am expecting to see the video file being displayed as ffmpeg is processing the output. But, I just see ffmpeg do its processing, and the Udp listener writing to the console.
Let me know where I am going wrong, thanks in advance

Comment: Any updates/progress on this?